# Insubordination by following rules precisely?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for "insubordination by following rules exactly"? (I think there may be a military term for this.)

The phrase "Work to rule" is similar, but to me feels more connected to industrial action.

Comment: Related [Term for when doing a job or work following all the rules and regulations](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331219/term-for-when-doing-a-job-or-work-following-all-the-rules-and-regulations#comment754780_331219)

Comment: There is a term "xxx compliance", but "xxx" isn't coming to me right now.

Comment: See also: [Peanut Butter Sandwich](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PeanutButterSandwich)

Comment: My best suggestion would be **Jobsworth** (origin: "It's more than my job's worth to bend the rules to help you...).

Comment: Oh, yeah!  "Malicious compliance."

Comment: @HotLicks Malicious compliance is great, thank you!

Comment: Malicious compliance is the behaviour of intentionally inflicting harm by strictly following the orders of a superior, knowing that compliance with the orders will not have the intended result. (I think this term may go beyond what the OP is asking for.)

Comment: @HotLicks should put `malicious compliance` as an answer so Leopoldo can accept it and the question can show up as answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phrase for observing a rule in a malicious way](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79793/phrase-for-observing-a-rule-in-a-malicious-way)

Answer (score 3):

"Malicious compliance" is a term for adhering to the precise letter of one's orders and instructions ("the letter of the law"), even when one is well aware that to do so is counter-productive to the organization's best interests, and often counter to the intent of the orders as well.

Unfortunately, I could not, in reviewing about a dozen different links on the topic, find a reference that is not grinding an axe of some shape, so all I can present is the skeleton description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance).  If you're interested in the topic probably the best thing to do is Google it and try to extract bits of pertinent info from several different articles that pop up.

Answer (score 2):

Within sports, this can be referred to as ***gamesmanship***, sticking to the letter but not the "spirit" of the rules, and doing things which would be considered "unsporting" but not illegal.

It's like the opposite side of the coin to "sportsmanship".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamesmanship