# Emphasizing or observing the letter but not the spirit of the law

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that refers to:

The emphasis or observation of a rule (or law) to the letter, in a way that violates the spirit (or original good intention) of that rule (or law).

Comment: Do you mean *Legalism*?

Comment: There's the perjorative *jobsworth*.

Comment: Great question.  Seems kind of like passive-aggressive, but it's more specific.  // The question can be strengthened with a context, an example sentence, and clarification as to how important it is to you that it be a *single* word.

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79793/phrase-for-observing-a-rule-in-a-malicious-way

Comment: @aparente001 Yeah, it is considered (DSM-IV) *malicious compliance*; a subset of *passive aggressive* behaviour. But that has the exclusive implication that malice is present and intentional. Basic single (or compound) root word(s) would be preferable.

Comment: Isn’t that called finding/exploiting a ***loophole?***

Comment: @Jim Yeah, for sure. In some specific contexts, it can be. But, similar to *malicious compliance*, it exclusively implies intentional *exploitation*, whereas that is not always the case. It could be due to a *bona fide error / accident / (honest) mistake*, *obsessive compulsion*, *unintentional ignorance*, *stupidity*, and so on. Also *loophole* is non-literary; a colloquial term.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - I was going to post that as the answer until I saw you had already suggested it as a comment.  Why not make it an answer?  I never understand why people bury legit answers in the comments.

Comment: Sorry but something (an act or actions) violates the spirit if not the letter of the law. So, this seems very odd to me. The reverse: violating the letter but not the spirit is impossible in legal terms anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"Pedantic?" "Pharasee?"(a member of an ancient Jewish sect, distinguished by strict observance of the traditional and written law)

Comment: You're on the right track. I don't feel like it fits because of the retroactive origin and culturally specific connotations of the term, but *Pharisaism* is seen being used this way in the following article: *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_faith#General_use*

Answer (score 2):

In a ***bureaucracy***, rules are so literally followed that often, the spirit in which the rule was made in the first place does not matter.

Collins:

> **[bureaucracy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bureaucracy)**
>   *noun* [plural -cies]
>
> **4.** any administration in which action is impeded by unnecessary official procedures and red tape
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © Harper Collins Publishers

Urban Dictionary:

> **[Bureaucracy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bureaucracy)**
>
> **2.** A form of government, the authority of which is not so much to accomplish anything, but to obstruct accomplishment by anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking to a **blind application of law** ?

For example:

> the  blind  application  of  law  can  occasion  injustices  which 
>   are potentially  greater  than  the  crime  being  policed.

.

> My point here is that the "law" has been changed in the past and the
>   situation must be evaluated based upon it merits. Sadly, the blind
>   application of law seems more important that looking at the merits.

Answer (score 1):

**gaming the system**

[here is how the Wikipedia explains the phrase 'gaming the system' in reference to exploiting their internal rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Gaming_the_system)

> Gaming the system means deliberately using Wikipedia policies and guidelines in bad faith to thwart the aims of Wikipedia. Gaming the system may represent an abuse of process, disruptive editing, or otherwise evading the spirit of community consensus. Editors typically game the system to make a point, to further an edit war, or to enforce a specific non-neutral point of view.

**bad faith** is a key component of gaming the system .. perhaps I should list it as a separate possibility/answer but bad faith applies in many situations beyond "letter of the law" issues. "**following rules in bad faith**" starts describing a situation when you're looking for a word for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is the letter of the law and the spirit of the law.

If you violate the spirit of the law, you are not violating the letter of the law.

However, if you violate the letter of the law, its spirit is surely impugned as well.

Comment: This does not address the question. And it's also incorrect: all four  combinations are possible.

Comment: Especially when the law is sloppily worded.

Comment: All four combinations?? It addresses the usual language used when using the expression letter of the law and spirit of the law....